# ListView Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am using a databound DataList in ASP.NET C# to create a tag cloud. Is there a way to make sure that each tag is rendered properly..i.e - have documentation and process and team composition on one line as the tag cloud grows? Here's my code - many thanks for your help!

```
<div style="padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 25px; text-align: center;">
<asp:listview runat="server" ID="ListView1" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href='<%# GenerateNegativeStoryDetails(Eval("Tag")) %>' style="color: #ff0000; text-align: center; margin: 15px; line-height: 30px; text-decoration:none; font-size: <%# GetTagSize(Convert.ToDouble(Eval("weight"))) %>"><%# Eval("Tag") %></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="negative_tags" runat="server" style="color: #ff0000;" Text="[NO NEGATIVE TAGS FOUND]"></asp:Label>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:listview>
</div>

<br />

<div style="padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 25px; text-align: center;">
<asp:listview runat="server" ID="ListView2" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href='<%# GeneratePositiveStoryDetails(Eval("Tag")) %>' style="color: #33cc00; text-align: center; margin: 15px; line-height: 3px; text-decoration:none; font-size: <%# GetTagSize(Convert.ToDouble(Eval("weight"))) %>"><%# Eval("Tag") %></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="positive_tags" runat="server" style="color: #33cc00;" Text="[NO POSITIVE TAGS FOUND]"></asp:Label>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:listview>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You may consider revising the question title, as your code sample uses a ListView, and the title indicates you need assistance with a DataList, which is a different animal entirely.

Comment: Good point - my mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider styling the element wrapping each individual phrase with the style:

```
white-space:nowrap
```

Comment: Would you mind inserting a screenshot with white-space:nowrap? Just curious

Answer (score 0):

Replace spaces in each tag with a non-breaking space
`GenerateNegativeStoryDetails(Eval("Tag").Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"))`